# issues in cc.net (cruisecontrol.net) with uppercut

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have installed uppercut integrated cc.net such a way that i didnt make any change in webdashboard,

This is my cc.net config code,

-->
    
    -->

```
<!-- PROJECT STRUCTURE -->
<cb:define name="WindowsFormsApplication1">
    <project name="$(projectName)">
        <workingDirectory>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)</workingDirectory>
        <artifactDirectory>$(drop_directory)\$(projectName)</artifactDirectory>
        <category>$(projectName)</category>
        <queuePriority>$(queuePriority)</queuePriority>
        <triggers>
            <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="60" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
        </triggers>
        <sourcecontrol type="svn">
            <executable>c:\program files\subversion\bin\svn.exe</executable>
            <!--<trunkUrl>http://192.168.1.8/trainingrepos/deepasundari/WindowsFormsApplication1</trunkUrl>-->
            <trunkUrl>$(svnPath)</trunkUrl>
            <workingDirectory>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)</workingDirectory>
        </sourcecontrol>
        <tasks>
            <msbuild>
                    <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
                    <workingDirectory>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)</workingDirectory>
                    <projectFile>WindowsFormsApplication1.sln</projectFile>
                    <timeout>600</timeout>
                  <buildArgs> /noconsolelogger /p:configuration=Debug </buildArgs>
                    <!--<buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:OutputPath=$(drop_directory)\$(projectName)\sample </buildArgs>-->
                    <logger>ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger,C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
            </msbuild>
            <!--<labeller type="svnRevisionLabeller">
                <prefix>Test-</prefix>
                <major>7</major>
                <minor>11</minor>
                <url>$svnpath</url>
                <username>deepasundari</username>
                <password>deepasundari</password>
            </labeller>-->

            <exec>
                <executable>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)\build.bat</executable>
            </exec>
        </tasks>
        <publishers>
            <!--<buildpublisher>
                --><!--<sourceDir>C:\myprojects\project1</sourceDir>--><!--
                <publishDir>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)</publishDir>
            </buildpublisher>-->

            <merge>
                <files>
                    <file>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)\build_output\build_artifacts\*.xml</file>
                    <file>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)\build_output\build_artifacts\mbunit\*-results.xml</file>
                    <file>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)\build_output\build_artifacts\nunit\*-results.xml</file>
                    <file>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)\build_output\build_artifacts\ncover\*-results.xml</file>
                    <file>$(working_directory)\$(projectName)\build_output\build_artifacts\ndepend\*.xml</file>

                </files>
            </merge>
            <!--<email from="buildserver@somewhere.com" mailhost="smtp.somewhere.com" includeDetails="TRUE">
                <users>
                    <user name="YOUR NAME" group="BuildNotice" address="yourEmail@somewhere.com" />
                </users>
                <groups>
                    <group name="BuildNotice" notification="change" />
                </groups>
            </email>-->
            <xmllogger/>
            <statistics>
                <statisticList>
                    <firstMatch name="Svn Revision" xpath="//modifications/modification/changeNumber" />
                    <firstMatch name="ILInstructions" xpath="//ApplicationMetrics/@NILInstruction" />
                    <firstMatch name="LinesOfCode" xpath="//ApplicationMetrics/@NbLinesOfCode" />
                    <firstMatch name="LinesOfComment" xpath="//ApplicationMetrics/@NbLinesOfComment" />
                </statisticList>
            </statistics>
            <modificationHistory onlyLogWhenChangesFound="true" />
            <rss/>
        </publishers>
    </project>
</cb:define>

<cb:WindowsFormsApplication1 projectname="WindowsFormsApplication1" queuepriority="1" svnpath="http://192.168.1.8/trainingrepos/deepasundari/WindowsFormsApplication1" />
```

this code is updating rss and report xml files, but i could not get the build folder in the code_drop..

could anyone help me with this problem??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have followed the sample almost perfectly. http://uppercut.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/Samples/CC.NET/server/ccnet.config

What you should see in the code_drop folder on the build server is a folder b##-r## for build and revision per each build.

Most of this is talked about in here: http://uppercut.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/IntegrateUppercuTWithCruiseControl.NET.doc